# Improving query performance with two inner joins on tables that have > 40M rows

Tags: postgresql, performance, join, cte

**Context**
I have three tables - nodes, edges and sections. This is a graph network of paths from open street maps where edges are created from two neighbouring 3D nodes (that give distance, elevation gain etc.) and sections are a collection of edges between decision nodes. In effect sections build on edges which build on nodes.
This is a Postgres 12.5 database running on AWS RDS service on a m5 Large instance.
In terms of size:
Nodes - 40M rows
Edges - 80M rows
Sections - 15M rows
The tables have the following indexes:

Nodes

- nodeid

Edges

- edgeid
- edgestartnode
- edgeendnode

Sections

- sectioned
- startnode

**Aim**
I have a routing algorithm that returns an ordered list of section ids that I then want to use in a query (below) to pull out the relevant information from the database (from the nodes, edges, and sections tables) so that I can plot it on a map and display relevant information to the user. The list of sections can contain thousands of values, with the query performance information related below to a list of length 8646.

db fiddle for query below [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oZSCBqdqm16ZABWuamwzxE/5)

```
SELECT row_to_json(results)
FROM (
SELECT id, edgeid, lat, lon, elevation AS elev, edgelength As dist, edgegradient AS grad
FROM (SELECT ord, sectionid as id, unnest(edgelist) as edges 
FROM unnest(ARRAY[IDs])
WITH ordinality AS arg_list(id, ord)
INNER JOIN sections s on s.sectionid = id
ORDER BY ord) as ed_list
INNER JOIN edges e on e.edgeid = ed_list.edges 
INNER JOIN nodes n on n.nodeid = e.edgeendnode) results;
```

**Issue**
If the database is 'cold' and hasn't been used in a geographical region recently, when this query runs it takes a very long time, with the following query plan [here](https://explain.depesz.com/s/I8HD).

However, if the query or a similar query is run in a short time after it, the performance is much better, as shown in this [plan](https://explain.depesz.com/s/dpcDp), with a 100X improvement.

**Question**
I've done a lot of reading about trying to improve joins and tried implementing different techniques, like [here](https://medium.com/squad-engineering/blazingly-fast-querying-on-huge-tables-by-avoiding-joins-5be0fca2f523) and tried the following query (db fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hWmfdmP37Mjv2qNtfyqeNh/6))

```
WITH sections_data(ord, id, edges) AS (
SELECT ord, sectionid as id, unnest(edgelist) as edges
FROM sections
JOIN   unnest(ARRAY[IDs]) WITH ORDINALITY t(sectionid, ord) USING (sectionid)
),
edge_data(ord, id, edgeid, end_node, dist, grad) AS (
SELECT ord, id, edgeid, edgeendnode as end_node, edgelength As dist, 
edgegradient AS grad FROM edges , sections_data WHERE edgeid = edges
),
node_data(ord, id, edgeid, lat, lon, elev, dist,  grad) AS (
SELECT ord, id, edgeid, lat, lon, elevation as elev, dist, grad FROM nodes, edge_data WHERE nodeid = end_node
)

SELECT row_to_json(results) FROM (SELECT id, edgeid, lat, lon, elev, dist, grad FROM node_data ORDER BY ord
) results;
```

but when I tried implementing that it resulted in a slightly slower query for me. So is there a better way to do it than I have currently?

Comment: we need some more information see https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions/3035#3035

Comment: What is the correlation (from pg_stats) of edges.edgeid?  If it is low, you could try doing  a CLUSTER of the table in it primary key index.

Comment: @nbk I've added more details including RDS instance size and a db fiddle for each of the different queries showing the data types and indexes, however it is not choosing the same plan as the the sample data is small. Do you know of a quick way for me to get a lot of rows into db Fiddle so that I have the number required to make it choose the plan I am discussing in this question?

Comment: @jjanes the correlation is 0.014487578. Would a CLUSTER  ultimately bring that number closer to 1 meaning the planner wouldn't have to scan the whole table?

Comment: Yes, increasing the correlation is the idea.  Then one disk read should bring in several relevant rows, not just one.  Unfortunately I think you have to try it to see if it works for you, and that will lock the table for a long time.